# Developers mode

Tags: foursquare

Is there a way to become a manager of a venue just for development purposes, without having to complete all the steps of claiming a venue? Maybe by creating a false venues and be manager of it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not entirely true as foursquare is actively encouraging developers _to ask questions **about the foursquare API** on Stack Overflow_ (see [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/support) and [here](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/12/02/redesigning-the-developer-websit/).

Answer (score 0):

For the Venue Push API, you can create a "home" venue and will automatically be treated as the manager of that venue.

For specials/stats, create a test venue and either go through the [claim flow](http://support.foursquare.com/entries/191119-how-do-i-claim-my-venue) for the venue, or e-mail api@foursquare.com and with the venue ID and your user ID, asking them to claim the venue for you.